# How to make sure that property will get its value after response?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Response is received without any problems, but properties which must be changed after response by received data are undefined. Probably they getting values from the temp variables way too fast. How to fix this?
By the way, is there an option to avoid those temp variables and use properties of the object inside if statement? It would be so much better. Tried different ways, but it didn't work =(

```
  var tickerBittrex = function(tickerName)
    {
        this.tickerName = tickerName;
        this.requestURL = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=" + tickerName;
        /* Properties */
        this.success = false;
        this.message = "";
        this.Last = 0;


        this.sendRequest = function()
        {   /* temp variables */
            var success;
            var message;
            var Last;

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(success, message, Last)
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                {
                   console.log(xhttp.responseText); // test

                   var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText); // parsed response

                   console.log(response); // test

                   success = response.success;
                   message = response.message;

                   Last = response.result.Last;

                   console.log(Last); // test

                   console.log("xhttp.status: " + xhttp.status + " readyStat:" + xhttp.readyStat); // test

                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", this.requestURL, true);
            xhttp.send();

            this.success = success;
            this.message = message;
            this.Last = Last;
        }

    }


    var bittrexBTC = new tickerBittrex("usdt-btc");
    bittrexBTC.sendRequest();
```

Comment: xhttp.readyStat is undefined?

Comment: What is the output of your `console.log(xhttp.responseText);`?

Comment: console.log(xhttp.responseText);

{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":7605.26000000,"Ask":7609.99999999,"Last":7610.00000000}}

Comment: So you must be talking about the `this.success = success;` not being set? These won't be set correctly as they are run before the `onreadystatechange` event. What are you attempting to do after this web request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
    var tickerBittrex = function(tickerName) {
        this.tickerName = tickerName;
        this.requestURL = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=" + tickerName;
        /* Properties */
        this.success = false;
        this.message = "";
        this.Last = 0;
        var self = this;

        this.sendRequest = function() { /* temp variables */


            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(success, message, Last) {
                var success;
                var message;
                var Last;
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log(xhttp.responseText); // test

                    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText); // parsed response

                    console.log(response); // test

                    success = response.success;
                    message = response.message;

                    Last = response.result.Last;

                    console.log(Last, success, message); // test
                    self.success = success;
                    self.message = message;
                    self.Last = Last;
                    console.log(self);
                    console.log("xhttp.status: " + xhttp.status + " readyState:" + xhttp.readyState); // test                   

                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", this.requestURL, true);
            xhttp.send();

        }


    }


    var bittrexBTC = new tickerBittrex("usdt-btc");
    bittrexBTC.sendRequest();
```

Explanation:

first,put code below  in the onreadystatechange callback because before the callback executed the value of success,message,Last will be undefined.

```
       this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
        this.Last = Last;
```

second:change this to self which defined in the tickerBittrex function,so can get the right this object.

```
        var self = this;
```

so comes:

```
       self.success = success;
        self.message = message;
        self.Last = Last;
```

[image: result]

Comment: I'm talking about properties of bittrexBTC object (Last: undefined
message: undefined
success: undefined)

Comment: @PoorProgrammer Last:7594.17177079 ,,message:'',success:true

Comment: @PoorProgrammer updated,now works for me ,test again.i will add explainsion

Comment: This will work to set these properties, but I fear you are going to miss a huge concept depending on how you anticipate using your `bittrexBTC` object in later code. The reason your original code is not working as intended is due to this `XMLHttpRequest` running asynchronously.

Comment: Works for me now as well. Thanks a lot, @xianshenglu.

Comment: @PhillipThomas I'm going to change content of some html tag using innerHTML property, and use bittrexBTC.Last property for some calculations later.

Comment: yes,you are right,he has to put the other callback in the readystatechange callback or change the true argument in  xhttp.open to false.He can't use the obj immediately

Comment: @PoorProgrammer notice that ,you can't use the obj immediately because the xhr needs time to get result and set those three attributes.If you want to ,you could put the other callback in the readystatechange callback,put it at the bottom or change the true argument in xhttp.open to false.